# 401 unauthorized on POST to /identity/externallogin

Tags: sitecore-client, federated-authentication, login

I am trying to enable federated authentication in my Sitecore 9.3 solution to login using Google Authentication. I have configued Sitecore more or less like this:

https://blog.nikkipunjabi.com/2018/02/sitecore-federated-authentication-part-1-authentication-google-facebook-identity-providers.html

https://blog.nikkipunjabi.com/2018/03/sitecore-federated-authentication-part-2-google-and-facebook-app-and-the-custom-processor.html

This is at least partially working. When I navigate to site.dk/sitecore/login, a new button has appeared below the User Name / Password fields. However, when I click the button...
[image]

but I immediately get a 401 from the server like that:
[image]

so can any one help me with that?!!

Comment: In SC9.3 you will have to create a subprovider in IdentityServer side if you want to use Federated Auth.

Comment: The articles you mentioned are only for Sc 8.x and Sc9 , post 9.1 , its changed

Comment: You should follow this documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/use-the-sitecore-identity-server-as-a-federation-gateway.html

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this, I had the same issue. [This community discussion post](https://community.sitecore.com/community/en?id=community_question&sys_id=b085a7e91b4770d0b8954371b24bcb93) had the answer :

```
new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
  // etc ...
  AuthenticationType = this.GetAuthenticationType(), // Make sure to include this
  // etc ....
});
```

Moral of the story is: pay closer attention to the required attributes :)